# JavascriptMVC: localStorage example?

Tags: local-storage, javascriptmvc

I'm trying to use JMVC's [localStorage plugin](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2010/05/21/html5-localstorage-for-javascriptmvc.html) to cache my models until I explicitly update them.

The only example I've found is the following, that says that I have to manually store the models in the local store.

```
function updateModel(params) {
  MyModel.store.destroy(params.id);
  MyModel.store.create(params);
}
```

I'm not sure how to apply that example to JMVC's regular model methods.  For example, how would I update this model's findAll() to look in the local store for models before executing the ajax call?

```
$.Model.extend('MyCachedModel',
{
    setup: function(){
        this.storeType = SS.Model.HTML5Store.Local;
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    findAll: function( params, success, error ){
        // How do I update this to store and retrieve models from localStorage?
        $.ajax({
            url: '/todo',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: params,
            success: this.callback(['wrapMany',success]),
            error: error,
            fixture: "//app/fixtures/todos.json.get" 
        });
        [...]
```

Thanks!